# wpf datagrid filter column header value access

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using control  datagrid filter control from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering and it is working fine.
I want to save filter conditions ( header textboxes  value ). 
How can I get header/textboxes value on any button click and again set some header textboxes in some other event.

[More details]
I am consuming Filter control in one of my wpf application.Downloaded project is also containing a  consumer test project (DataGridFilterTest).  add a simple button with click event outside the grid ( no relation with grid).NOw I filter the data with some text in header column textbox. The added button click event i want the value or object of this textbox.Idea is I will save these text somewhere in xml and later on next time ( new request),i ll open grid with pre fixed data filter with same text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What a about a method like this one, where you go through the `VisualTree` to get the desired values. Once you have the `DataGridColumnHeader` and `DataGridColumnCell` is easy to get the value:

```
private void DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender,
                                                  MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((dep != null) &amp;&amp;
            !(dep is DataGridCell) &amp;&amp;
            !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader)
    {
        DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = dep as DataGridColumnHeader;
        // do something
    }

    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
        // do something
    }
}
```

I took it from here http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html, it can be very useful for you

Comment: thanks Juan,I am able to get datagrid column header with either datagrid.Columns or ColumnHeaderStyle property under button click but unable ti get textbox and other filter controls ( datetime) object and their propeties.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem. Here is a solution. It might not be the most elegant one, but it works.

In the Datagrid's Loaded event, find the TextBox elements. You can use the algorithm written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684336/wpf-get-item-of-itemscontrol-in-visualtree). You can narrow down the elements by checking their names, which will be "PART_TextBoxFilter", and their type will be DataGridFilterLibrary.Support.DelayTextBox (which descends from TextBox). It will still find more than you need, you can check if their binding paths are not empty (that is not part of the below sample). The point is to hook a KeyDown event handler on them:

```
void dgFilter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(sender as DataGrid))
    {
        if (tb != null && tb.Name == "PART_TextBoxFilter")
        {
            tb.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbDelayTextBox_KeyUp);
        }
    }
}
```

In the event handler method, the filter values can be reached, but that is not enough. The name of the binding path must be saved as well, otherwise you will not know which column it should filter. Furthermore, you can have multiple datagrids in your window, so the name of the datagrid is also important.
I used a Dictionary for saving the filters.

```
Dictionary<string,string> filterValues;
void tbDelayTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string dgName;
    var bindingPath = DelayTextBoxBindingPath(sender as DataGridFilterLibrary.Support.DelayTextBox, out dgName);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingPath))
    {
        var key = dgName + "_" + bindingPath;
        if (filterValues.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            filterValues[key] = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
        }
        else
        {
            filterValues.Add(key, ((TextBox)sender).Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method to get the binding path and the datagrid's name:

```
string DelayTextBoxBindingPath(DataGridFilterLibrary.Support.DelayTextBox __dtb, out string datagridName)
{
    datagridName = String.Empty;
    var result = String.Empty;

    if (__dtb != null)
    {
        BindingExpression be = __dtb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty) as BindingExpression;
        if (be != null)
        {
            var dgcf = be.DataItem as DataGridFilterLibrary.DataGridColumnFilter;
            if (dgcf != null && dgcf.FilterCurrentData != null)
            {
                result = dgcf.FilterCurrentData.ValuePropertyBindingPath;
                datagridName = dgcf.DataGrid.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

To save/load the filter, you can use the window's OnClosing, and the Datagrid's Loaded event (above), respectively.

Hope this helps.